# При открытии фрагмента из NavigationDrawer'a получаю пустой listView

Tags: android-sdk, android, listview, android-fragment

Здравствуйте!
Такая проблема: При открытии фрагмента из `NavigationDrawer`'a получаю пустой `listView`.
Данные загружаю в `doInBackGround()` с сервера. Запрос точно рабочий, в манифесте все как надо. Как я понимаю форма открывается раньше,чем приходят данные с сервера, а когда приходят то форма не обновляется. Не знаю как решить проблему. Спасибо

```
public class MyEmployeFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_ID = "p_id";
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "p_name";
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME = "p_last_name";
    ArrayList<spr_item> ret_data;
    MyTask task;
    SimpleAdapter sAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        task = new MyTask();
        task.execute();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_employe, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ret_data = new ArrayList<spr_item>();

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                ret_data.size());
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < ret_data.size(); i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_ID, ret_data.get(i).getId());
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ret_data.get(i).getName());
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME, ret_data.get(i).getLastName());
            data.add(m);
        }

        // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
        String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_LAST_NAME};
        // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
        int[] to = {R.id.tw_employe_id, R.id.tw_employe_name, R.id.tw_employe_last_name};

        // создаем адаптер
         sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.list_item_employee,
                from, to);

            // определяем список и присваиваем ему адаптер
            ListView lvSimple = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);

    }

         class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

             @Override
             protected void onPreExecute() {
                 super.onPreExecute();

             }

             @Override
             protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                 String s = "5ACACEC6-752B-4EFF-AA50-EEBE58A52113";
                 // String user_guid = myPrefs.getString("guid", "");

                 HttpActivity _http = new HttpActivity("192.168.10.11", "80");
                 _http.set_addr_protocol("/WebSite/P/spr/spr.aspx/");
                 _http.add_param("query", "spr_employee_get");
                 // _http.add_param("p_guid", user_guid.toString().trim());
                 _http.add_param("p_guid", s);
                 _http.send();

                 List<spr_item> tempList = _http.getArrayParamValue();
                 for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++)
                     ret_data.add(tempList.get(i));

                 //employer_name = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_name");
                 //employer_id = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_id");
                 //employer_last_name = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_last_name");

                 return null;
             }

             protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                 super.onPostExecute(result);
                 sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените

```
ret_data = _http.getArrayParamValue();
```

на

```
List<spr_item> tempList = _http.getArrayParamValue();
for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++)
    ret_data.add(tempList.get(i));
```

а в  ***onPostExecute(Void result)*** вызовите  ***sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();***

Вы передаете в адаптер List<>, а затем в переменную присваиваете другую ссылку, тем самым адаптер смотрит на одну область памяти, а ret_data на другую

Comment: Сделал все как Вы сказали. В метод onPostExecute вставил sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); среда выделила эту строку красным, и я сдеал локальную переменную  SimpleAdapter sAdapter; В итоге пустой listView. Что не так делаю?

Comment: @Garf1eld обновите код свой

Comment: @Andreich обновил

Comment: @Garf1eld вы пробовали смотреть сколько элементов в tempList, когда вы получаете данные?

Comment: @Andreich да, там те данные которые нужны. В моем случае size = 2

Comment: @Garf1eld да, интересно, но так, без дебага, я уже не могу ничего сказать. Могу лишь предположить, что у вас проблемы с адаптером. Я бы вам посоветовал написать реализацию ArrayAdapter. Во всяком случае это будет полезно. http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/

Comment: @Garf1eld, а зачем Вы сделали ЛОКАЛЬНУЮ переменную? Вам нужно не у локальной переменной вызвать notifyDataSetChanged(), а именно у того адаптера, который у Вас используется.